# Creating a pattern with a nested while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

Hey im an totale beginner, this is what Im trying to recreate `'4444\n3333\n2222\n1111\n'`. Im trying to do this with an nested while loop. this is what I have now.

```
print()
fig = ''
i = side
while i >= side: 
 j = 1
 while j >= i: 
   fig += str(i)
   j += 1
 fig += '\n'
 i += 1

print()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- if `i` starts at `side` and is increasing, then `i >= side` will always be true

  - `i` should be descreasing, and bound `>0`
- `j` should not be bound by `i`, but by `side`
- finally, your should print `fig`

```
side = 4
fig = ''
i = side
while i > 0:
    j = 1
    while j < side:
        fig += str(i)
        j += 1
    fig += '\n'
    i -= 1

print(fig)
```

---

With for loop

```
side = 4
fig = ''

for i in range(side, 0, -1):
    fig += str(i) * side + "\n"
```